# Angular2 no respeta estilos cargados desde un componente

Tags: angularjs-2.0

soy nuevo en *Angular 2* y siguiendo la guía de la pagina oficial, en la sección de "basics" primera parte (`ngmodule`) da un ejemplo en la versión 3 de como carga un archivo `css` desde el componente de contacto. En su ejemplo online funciona pero en mi local no se respetan los estilos.

Saben porque podría ser?

Gracias.

Comment: Lautaro, por favor aclara un poco más tu pregunta agregando el código relevante de tu proyecto. Te sugiero que sigas esta guía: [mcve].

Comment: Finalmente fue por llamar incorrectamente los estilos. Pido disculpas.